# Is "reflectionally" a word?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say two shapes are "reflectionally symmetric"?
Or do I need to say they are "reflectively symmetric"?
Or are both words correct, but with different meanings?
Or are both words incorrect?

Comment: It's redundant. That's what symmetric (by itself) means. If you mean something else, like rotational symmetry, you use a modifier.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Great point! although it doesn't answer the question

Comment: You could just say that they are "symmetric under reflection".

Comment: @PeterShor: Yeah, but it doesn't fit well in a sentence in which the others use the original form, disregarding the redundancy that curiousdannii pointed out. (e.g. "shapes A and B are rotationally and reflectionally symmetric" sounds much better than"shapes A and B are rotationally symmetric and symmetric under reflection".)

Comment: Do you want *bilaterally symmetric*, eg like the human body?

Comment: @DanBron: Yeah, but since it's in a mathematical context rather than a biological one I want to emphasize the word "reflection" (since that's the operation).

Comment: Regardless, since my curiosity is piqued I would like to know the answer to this question itself, not to get sidetracked about the proper word usage. (But thank you for the suggestions nonetheless.)

Comment: The reason for all the suggestions is that people here are instinctively balking at "*reflectionally*". Nevertheless, in sure if you searched arXiv or any other body of mathematical papers, you'd find instances of the word, because technical communities have their own rules and patterns in language. Having said that, neither "*reflectional*"   nor "*reflectionally*" appear in [Symmetry, by Herman Weyl](http://bit.ly/194KwE5), which appears to be one of the standard reference works in the field (he calls these symmetries *bilateral* or *mirror*).

Comment: There is an entry in Wiktionary http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reflectionally but that can't be trusted as anyone can make up definitions there but it's a good start. Check Google Books, and there's _reflectionally_ aplenty (often with _symmetric_). https://www.google.com/search?q=reflectionally+&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl So it's a word.

Comment: @curiousdannii It's not redundant. What you imply is the only meaning when unmodified is the  more usual one, but not the default one. _Shapes A and B are both symmetric: A reflectionally, and B both reflectionally and rotationally._ But A and B are both symmetric.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just realized that I get a spelling error for "rotationally" as well.

Comment: @Frank: Good point, it didn't occur to me to search Google Books. I just did a web search and didn't find anything nontechnical (aside from the wiktionary entry) so that's why I asked.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Default meanings are important to recognise. We would interpret your example there as being the generic meaning only because the immediate context discuss both types of symmetry. If nothing more was said in the context then *symmetric* wouldn't just imply reflectional symmetry, it would mean it too.

Comment: @curiousdannii I've often asked 'Does shape A have symmetry' or 'Is shape A symmetric', expecting a _yes_ answer to be accompanied by a statement of the type (and order) of symmetry involved (if any). I repeat, 'reflective symmetry' is the more common sense of 'symmetry' but can _not_ be assumed. Some dictionaries say the terms 'reflective symmetry' and 'symmetry' are non-hyponymous/hypernymous, but others say they are not. So there's room for confusion. So 'reflectional symmetry' disambiguates. So the term isn't tautologous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay, I can see there are some contexts where it might not be perfectly clear.

Comment: If you don't like "reflectionally", you could just say that "shapes A and B are symmetric under rotation and reflection".

Comment: I say: go ahead and use it in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Two items that share a reflection symmetry are ***bilaterally symmetric***.

> For an arbitrary shape, the axiality of the shape measures how close it is to being **bilaterally symmetric**. It equals 1 for shapes with reflection symmetry, and between 2/3 and 1 for any other shape.
>
> <sup>*([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_symmetry#Symmetric_geometrical_shapes))* [emphasis mine]</sup>

Comment: Doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Sure it does. The answer to your question is in the subtext: don't use words that aren't words; use this instead.